# Why doesn't PlusMinus[a]^2 simplify to a^2?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

So, I've been playing around with Mathematica lately, and I found an interesting (what I presume to be an) error. Trying to simplify `(PlusMinus[a])^2` does not give a result of `a^2`. However, it is a fact that $(\pm a)^2 == a^2$.

Obviously, this is fairly easy to work around, but it does require splitting your work up into two (or more, depending on how many times you use `PlusMinus`) separate pieces.

So, am I missing something, or is this an error on *Mathematica*'s part?

Comment: PlusMinus[x,y,\[Ellipsis]] has no built-in meaning. See also [Operators without Built‐in Meanings](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `PlusMinus[a]` displays as $\pm x$.

I believe it is purely a formatting function. It is not literally interpreted as $\pm x$. However, per the documentation, you can *assign* values to it.

You can assign a rule that mimics the behavior you want by assigning an `UpValue` to `PlusMinus`:

```
PlusMinus /: PlusMinus[a_]^2 := a^2
```

Then:

```
UpValues@PlusMinus
(* { HoldPattern[(\[PlusMinus]a_)^2] :> a^2 } *)
```

and

```
PlusMinus[5]^2
(* 25 *)
```

---

As pointed out by [Lou](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9660/lou) in a comment, `PlusMinus` is one of the [Operators without Built-in Meanings](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html), which means that

```
PlusMinus[x,y,[Ellipsis]]
```

doesn't evaluate, it just displays.